# Flash of unloaded content when navigating in Blazor Server

Tags: c#, blazor, .net-6.0, blazor-server-side

I have some Blazor Server UI that's displaying some user-specific content:

```
<AuthorizeView>
    <Authorizing>
        <span class="spinner"></span>
    </Authorizing>
    <NotAuthorized>
        not logged in
    </NotAuthorized>
    <Authorized>
        logged in as @context.User.Identity!.Name
    </Authorized>
</AuthorizeView>
```

I'm currently using a custom `AuthenticationStateProvider` to track the login session.  It stores a user token in browser session storage on login and during first render it fetches the token and retrieves the session info on the backend.  This much is all working fine.

If the service is recreated and the state queried before first render, since it can't access JS yet, it simply returns "not logged in" and then requeries after first render.  (As far as I can tell it's not possible to keep it in the "authorizing" state by not completing the Task as this stalls the prerender.)

```
private readonly ProtectedSessionStorage _Storage;
private bool _HasLoaded;

public AuthorizationService(ProtectedSessionStorage storage) => _Storage = storage;

public void AfterFirstRender()
{
    _HasLoaded = true;
    NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(GetAuthenticationStateAsync());
}

public override async Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
{
    if (!_HasLoaded)  // prerendering
    {
        return new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal());
    }

    // ... code to fetch the real identity from _Storage
}
```

The problem is that when the user clicks an ordinary local navigation link (page to page within the same app via `<a href="pageX">`), this appears to tear down and rebuild all the scoped services, so it loses the authentication state and has to query it again -- but since it can't do that before first render, there is always a flash of "not logged in" on every navigation before it finishes reloading the state and updates, which is ugly.  (It's very fast, but still visible.  It's more visible if you deliberately add a delay to the process.)

I do have prerendering enabled (as per default) but I'm surprised that it seems to be triggering a full prerender+reload on every navigation instead of preserving state.  (I expect that on a full reload, or manual location edit, but not from internal navigation.)

When using WebAssembly, this just worked -- both singletons and scopes were per-session and navigations happened internally without discarding any state.  Not so with Server, apparently; singletons survive but are larger than per-user or per-session, and scopes seem to be per-page, which is smaller than per-session.

Am I missing some key trick to get this to behave sensibly?  Either to avoid the re-prerender on navigate or to keep scoped service states, or reload them reliably before JS render, or pass some kind of session id from pre-navigation to prerendering?  The official docs basically just "this exercise is left to the reader", but without at least *some* kind of id preservation I don't see how it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

Blazor server calls GetAuthenticationStateAsync() upon a new visit. This is the place to look for a previously saved cookie and authenticate the user accordingly. Next code will give you the clue.
First time it will silently catch an exception due to missing JS but it is immediately called a second time successfully:

```
    public override async Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
    {
        //get claimsPrincipal from stored user if within a session
        //or get it from cookie if a new session
        //return AuthenticationState from claimsPrincipal
        //or return anonymous if user throws error on modifying sessionstore by hand
        try
        {
            var storedUser = await TryGetUserFromBrowserStorage();
            if (storedUser == null) storedUser = await TryGetUserFromPersistedCookie();
            var claimsPrincipal = IdentityFromUserAccount(storedUser);
            return await Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(claimsPrincipal));
        }
        catch
        {
            //silently fails on prerrendering since JS is not available yet
            return await Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(_anonymous));
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is slightly simpler in that it doesn't need the explicit `AfterFirstRender` callback, but it still has the flash of unauthenticated content on every page navigation, so it doesn't really solve the question as asked.  And I dislike the speculative exceptions-as-control-flow pattern as a general rule.

Comment: Fully agree, but I could not find a better solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this recently and thought I'd share my solution.  I needed to pass some dynamic data stored in browser storage to the pre-rendered component and no matter what I tried, I couldn't get the data because pre-rendering occurs during the OnInitialized lifecycle method, and JSInterop cannot be used at that time.

I ended up developing a solution that used cookies instead of browser storage that works quite well for me.    Unfortunately, you still need to use JSInterop to write the cookie, but since this will always be done after OnInitialized, JSInterop will be available - it just adds a bit of complexity to the solution.

**Javascript functions - add to wwwroot/index.html, App.razor (.Net8) or separate javascript file**

```
<script>
    function setCookie(name, value, days) {
        var expires = "";
        if (days) {
            var date = new Date();
            date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
            expires = "; expires=" + date.toUTCString();
        }
        document.cookie = name + "=" + (value || "") + expires + "; path=/";
    }
    function getCookie(name) {
        var nameEQ = name + "=";
        var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
            if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
        }
        return null;
    }
</script>
```

I then create extension methods to JSInterop to interact with the Javascript functions so that I can use it anywhere I use JSInterop:

```
public static class AppJSRuntimeExtensions
{
    public static async Task<string> GetCookie(this IJSRuntime jsRuntime, string cookieName)
    {
        string? cookieVal = await jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("getCookie", cookieName);
        return cookieVal;
    }

    public static async Task SetCookie(this IJSRuntime jsRuntime, string cookieName, string cookieValue, int days)
    {
        await jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("setCookie", cookieName, cookieValue, days);
    }
}
```

In the component where you set the cookie value, you'll need to include something like the following:

```
@inject IJSRuntime jSRuntime

private async Task SetCookie(string name, string value, int days)
{
    await JSRuntime.SetCookie(name, value, days);
}
```

Then in the authentication state provider, you check for the presence of an HttpContext (this means that it will be running as Blazor Server - which it will be if the component is pre-rendering) and then you can retrieve the cookie value per the following:

```
public class CustomAuthenticationStateProvider : AuthenticationStateProvider
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
    
    public CustomAuthenticationStateProvider(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor )
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public override async Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
    {
        HttpContext? context = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;
        
        if(context != null) //ie running as Blazor Server
        {
            KeyValuePair<string, string>? cookie = context.Request.Cookies.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "cookieName");

            string cookieValue = cookie.Value.Value;

            //Use cookie Value as required to complete retrieving the Authentication State
        }
    }
}
```